# Asp.NET MVC 5 Update navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I need to update which entity is associated to the main entity but when i update it only changes the Id when i use the debugger, it does not change the entity associated to it on navigation property...

here are the models

Main Entity

```
public class Parametro
{
    public Parametro()
    {
        AlcanceAbastecimento = 3; // Default Nº PAB
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public int NumTurnos { get; set; }
    public int NumPAB { get; set; }   
    public int? AlcanceAbastecimento { get; set; }
    public int QtdMin { get; set; }
    public int QtdMax { get; set; }
    public int UAPId { get; set; }

    public UAP UAP { get; set; } // Associated entity
}

public class UAP
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Parametro Parametro { get; set; }
}
```

this is a one to one relation

on Edit here is the view

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UAPId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["UAPS"], "Selecione um UAP", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })`

and the controller for post on edit

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,NumTurnos,NumPAB,AlcanceAbastecimento,QtdMin,QtdMax,UAPId")] Parametro parametro)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(parametro).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        using (db)
        {
            ViewData["UAPS"] = new SelectList(db.UAP.ToList(), "Id", "Nome");
        }

        return View(parametro);
    }
```

and on fluent api

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<UAP>()
                        .HasOptional(u => u.Parametro) /
                        .WithRequired(p => p.UAP); /
        }
```

here it only changes the UAPId but not the actual entity. What am i missing?

Comment: The update doesn't do a ready afterwards, you will need to do another read of the entity to get the updated navigation property.

Comment: could you show me an example? I am a bit confused because I have used EF Core before and using attach it was different and much easier

Comment: Why do you need to reload the navigation property after a successful save? You are immediately redirecting back to the Index which should reload all the Parametros.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more clearly? Are you talking about the selectlist?

Comment: Well, what are you updating - the UAPs or Parametros? If you are simply editing a Parametro and then going back to the Index(List), then there is no need to repopulate the UAP property of the Parametro since you will be refetching the list from the database in your GET method.

Comment: i see, i thought i should be able to change which UAP is associated with the Parametro in this one to one relation

Comment: You can. Just update UAPId with the new value. On next read it will be changed.